# Ajax как вывести ошибки запроса

Tags: javascript, ajax

При отправки формы мне прилетают ошибки из запросы, как мне вывести их в мою форму?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#regFrom").on('submit' ,function (e) { //устанавливаем событие отправки для формы с id=form
        e.preventDefault();
        var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //собераем все данные из формы
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", //Метод отправки
            async: true,
            url: $(this).attr('action'), //путь до php фаила отправителя
            data: form_data,
            success: function (response) {
                if(response.error) {
                    alert(response.Text);
                }else{
                alert('ВСЕ ОК');
                }
            }
        });
        return false;

    });
});
```

[image: ответ]

Comment: что значит "как"?

Comment: Мне надо вывести их под input в форме

Comment: окей. есть селекторы и функции работы с селекторами. ты знаешь о них что-то?

Comment: да, но я пытаюсь вывести ошибки хотя-бы в консоль, вместо них прилетает просто POST 422 (Unprocessable Content)

Comment: Так может и надо было задавать именно этот вопрос с самого начала?...... А что тогда на скрине, если ты говоришь совсем другое?

Comment: К тому же то, что в коде у тебя явно отличается от имён ключей на скрине